# Start debugging button unavailable in a VS2012 project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm using visual studio 2012 and I don't find the button start for debugging. 
Instead, there a button "Attach".
How is it possible to enable Start button.
I have only one project in the solution that I imported from vs2010.
When a create a new project from scratch, Start is available.

Answer (score 21):

You can solve this issue by right clicking the project in Visual Studio and setting it as the 'StartUp Project'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it turned out that, even though the status bar was blank, it was still building (reeeeally slowly).